# Macro not resolving as expected

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to resolve an macro which changes during loop execution since i have defined it inside a single quote it's not getting resolved

%do m = 1 %to 10;

```
proc sql noprint;
    connect to POSTGRES (&prep_con_str);
    select run_date
        into :m_batch_dt
            from connection to POSTGRES (
                select min(run_date) - INTERVAL '&m. day' as run_date
                    from dummy; 
                                );
    disconnect from POSTGRES;
quit;
```

%end;

Comment: Does postgres allow you to use double quotes instead of single quotes?

Comment: What is your end goal? Wouldn't this macro be overwriting the `m_batch_dt` variable each time the loop runs?

Answer (score 0):

If postgres allows it, change to double quotes.

If not, maybe try macro quoting, e.g.:

```
%str(%')&m. day%str(%')
```